# css how to fix paragraph inside border box

Tags: html, css

hello i am  new in HTML and CSS now i have a problem with paragraph text it is overlapping i don't know how to solve this.
here is the picture

[image]

here is the code i wrote.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .box{
        padding: 10px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>
    <div class="box">
        hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hellohello hello hello hello hello hello
        hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-word`;

Here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to learn more

```css
.box {
     padding: 10px;
     width: 500px;
     height: 200px;
     border:1px solid red;
     word-break: break-word;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hellohello hello hello hello hello hello
        hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for

```
.box{
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```